# when i am using command gatsby new filename after that file is created but got error this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gatsby

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

```
  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm inst

  - error.js:56 makeError
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:56:11

  - index.js:114 handlePromise
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:114:26

  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5

  - init-starter.js:135 install
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:135:7

  - init-starter.js:202 clone
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:202:3

  - init-starter.js:343 initStarter
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:343:5

  - create-cli.js:485
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:485:9
```

pls help

node version - v13.5.0
npm version - 6.13.4
gatsby cli version - 2.17.0

Comment: Please show the entire error output. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65641143/edit) your question to include details.

Answer (score 0):

This [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27548) shows up the same issue as you, and it's fixed in multiple ways:

- Removing/trailing the whitespace in the directory name
- Running the following commands:

  - `npm cache clean or npm cache clean --force`
  - `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
  - `npm install` (if the socket throws a timeout exception repeat the `npm install` command)
  - `npm run develop`/`gatsby develop`
- `cd` to your project directory and run the command from there:

Comment: thank you for your response but I have used this

Comment: Next time provide that information in your answer, it's easier to help if we know what have you tried so far. Have you tried running a fresh installation in a new directory? Using: `npm init gatsby`

Comment: No, I have just used gatsby new filename cmd and got this error